# Media Capture - photos taken by phone are dark

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to make app that takes photo when you click on livetile. Unfortunately there is some problem on smartphones: photos saved by this app are entirely black. I have no idea what could I do wrong.

Facts:

1. This UWP app works on PC correctly, problem appears only on my Lumia device
2. Camera is correctly detected
3. This is not problem with livetile: it doesn't work no matter I take photo by clicking livetile or clicking on button
4. Not all photos are entirely black. When I take photo of a window (which is bright due to sunlight) I can see its fuzzy shape. Maybe photos are taken correctly, but they are somehow darkened?

There is too much code to paste, so I decided to publish entire project on GitHub.

[[LINK TO GITHUB]](https://github.com/MyPCIsBetter/Take-photo-by-tapping-tile)

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work? This code is mostly copied from one of tutorials, so it's quite strange that there is a problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found soultion:

After initializing MediaCapture and before taking photo, you need to create CaptureElement and start previewing.

```
var captureElement = new CaptureElement();
captureElement.Source = _mediaCapture;

await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

[Why you need to start previewing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15390861/1804027)

> dark pictures are often due to the lack of video preview. Camera drivers use the preview stream to run their 3A algorithms (auto-whitebalance/focus/exposure).

[Why you need to create Capture Element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190537/1804027)

> This error [that is shown when you use StartPreviewAsync without CaptureElement] occurs because currently StartPreviewAsync requires a sink to output frames to. This can be fixed by creating a capture element in xaml to display the frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet (from FingerPaint app) to change Hue or Lightness after image was taken:

```
    ImageEncodingProperties imageEncodingProps = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageEncodingProps, memoryStream);

        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(memoryStream);
        PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        byte[] pixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();

        for (int index = 0; index < pixels.Length; index += 4)
        {
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(pixels[index + 3],
                                         pixels[index + 2],
                                         pixels[index + 1],
                                         pixels[index + 0]);
            HSL hsl = new HSL(color);
            hsl = new HSL(hsl.Hue, 1.0, hsl.Lightness);
            color = hsl.Color;

            pixels[index + 0] = color.B;
            pixels[index + 1] = color.G;
            pixels[index + 2] = color.R;
            pixels[index + 3] = color.A;
        }

        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, 
                                                     (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        Stream pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        bitmap.Invalidate();

        image.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've just found easier solution